# Linting / format rule for a whole project

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to make a rule that lint all my code (every languages that I use on this project).
But I'm having some hard time making this.

As I said, the best idea that came in my mind to lint the whole project was to create a `lint` rule and put every linting rules in it (`eslint` for js & ts, `golang/lint` for go, etc...).

Here's my current rule:

```py
# //:rules/lint.bzl

load("@npm//eslint:index.bzl", "eslint")

def _lint(ctx):
  # js / ts
  eslint(
    name = "eslint",
    args = [
      "\"**/*.{ts, js}\"", # I don't think this is going to work, maybe with `location`?
    ],
  )

lint = rule(
  implementation = _lint,
)
```

And in my root's `BUILD.bazel`:

```py
# //:BUILD.bazel

load("//:rules/lint.bzl", "lint")

lint(name = "lint")
```

If I try to `bazel run //:lint` it throw me this:

```
ERROR: Cannot run target //:lint: Not executable
```

And with `bazel build`:

```
ERROR: /home/anatole/dev/Iris/BUILD.bazel:12:1: in lint rule //:lint:
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/anatole/dev/Iris/BUILD.bazel", line 12
                lint(name = 'lint')
        File "/home/anatole/dev/Iris/rules/lint.bzl", line 4, in _lint
                eslint(name = "eslint", <1 more arguments>)
        File "/home/anatole/.cache/bazel/_bazel_anatole/dea21c474582f8d9afdfb2cbf2e414cf/external/npm/eslint/index.bzl", line 11, in eslint
                nodejs_binary(<5 more arguments>)
rule() can only be called during the loading phase
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:lint' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '//:lint' failed; build aborted
```

And I have no idea why because if I directly put the `eslint` rule in my root's `BUILD.bazel` it  doesn't throw any error (but there's still this `**/*.{ts, js}` issue).

Maybe there's a better way to do all this, I'm beginning with Bazel.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking more for a macro, which can put a bunch of rules together, rather than a custom starlark rule.

Try first getting `eslint` to work the way you want it in a `BUILD.bazel` file, which might look like this:

```py
load("@npm//eslint:index.bzl", "eslint")

eslint(
  name = "eslint",
  srcs = glob(["**/*.js", "**/*.ts"]),
)
```

Then once that's working, you can move that into a macro in a separate bzl file:

`lint.bzl`:

```py
load("@npm//eslint:index.bzl", "eslint")

def lint():

  eslint(
    name = "eslint",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.js", "**/*.ts"]),
  )
```

Then your `eslint` call in your original `BUILD.bazel` file can become:

```py
load("//lint:lint.bzl", "lint")

# other rules

lint()
```

Comment: How can I run `lint`? `bazel run //:lint` doesn't seems to find `//:lint`

Comment: the `lint()` macro call creates a bunch of other rules, in this example it creates `//:eslint`. it doesn't really exist on its own. How to get all of these to run in a single bazel invocation will be tricky, since they're all different rules, probably with different ways to trigger them. Once you have the list of all the linters you want to use, it might be a good idea to gather them up and ask the question to bazel-discuss@googlegroups.com

Comment: Hi, have you configured this successfully?